# Return n largest nonzero entries of an array

Tags: algorithm, julia

For something I'm working on, I need a function that takes in a one-dimensional array `vec` of integers and returns a boolean array of the same shape indicating where the `n` largest entries of `vec` are located.

For example,

- `nlargest([0, 1, 3, 5], 2)` should yield `[0, 0, 1, 1]`.
- `nlargest([0, 0, 4, 0, 3, 6], 2)` should yield `[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]`.
- `nlargest([2, 1, 4, 3], 1)` should yield `[0, 0, 1, 0]`.

I have decided it's worthwhile to write my own function to do this, because the input data in this case has a few "nice" properties:

- `n` is always strictly smaller than the number of nonzero entries in `vec` and greater than zero
- The nonzero entries are all positive integers and there are no ties among them

Here is a working Julia function that does this:

```
function nlargest(vec, n)
    # Boolean vector shaped like input indicating n largest entries
    inp = copy(vec)
    out = zeros(Bool, length(vec))
    for i in 1:n
        am = argmax(inp)
        out[am] = true
        inp[am] = -1
    end
    return out
end
```

**I am more interested in the design of the algorithm itself than the specific Julia implementation**, so here is equivalent pseudocode:

- Initialize: `out` ← a array of boolean `0`s shaped like `vec`
- Repeat `n` times:

  - `j` ← `argmax(vec)`
  - Set the `j`th entry of `out` to `1`
  - Set the `j`th entry of `vec` to `-1` (*)
- Return `out`

(*) is taking advantage of the fact that all the nonzero entries are positive, but it feels like a bit of a hack to me. An alternative idea I had for this step was to "pop" the `j`th entry out of `vec` so that `argmax(vec)` has shorter input on the next loop. But it seems to me that the time savings there are offset by then having to adjust subsequent `j` values based on the new length of `vec`. **Is this reasoning sound, or is there something clever I can do here?**

**Have I taken full advantage of the structure of my input data?** Can I do better than the default `argmax()` function?

Of course, feedback on the Julia implementation is also welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm you described has complexity `O(n * m)`, where `m` is the size of the input array, since you run a full `argmax` at every one of the `n` iterations.

You can achieve the same thing by collecting the indices of the `n` largest values once, and then set only those indices to `1` in the result array.  For finding of the `n` largest values, you could use a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)), but Julia makes this easier with [`partialsortperm`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/sort/#Base.Sort.partialsortperm):

```
function nlargest(v, n; rev=true)
    result = falses(size(v))
    result[partialsortperm(v, 1:n; rev=rev)] .= true
    return result
end
```

This uses a `BitArray` for storage; if `n << m`, even a sparse array might pay off.  It should have complexity `O(m + n log n)`, unless I'm misjudging `partialsortperm`.  Note that sorting algorithms in Julia work ascending by default, so you have to use `rev=true` to get the equivalent of your code.

Comment: Once again I am pleasantly surprised to find a Julia builtin for something I had been coding my way around. Thank you!